# JavaFX Вывод списка файлов в TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

Есть такой `TableView`, выводящий список файлов:

```
public class OverLimitFilesLayoutController {

    private Stage OLFilesLayoutStage;

    public OverLimitFilesLayoutController() {}

    public ObservableList<File> currentOverLimitList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public ObservableList<OLLFile> oLLFileDataForView = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML private TableView<OLLFile> overLFilesTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<OLLFile, String> fileNameColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<OLLFile, Long> fileSizeColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<OLLFile, String> filePathColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<OLLFile, String> fileActions;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        initDataForView(currentOverLimitList);                                              //Преобразуем данные для отображения в таблице

        // устанавливаем тип и значение которое должно хранится в колонке
        fileNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OLLFile, String>("fileName"));
        fileSizeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OLLFile, Long>("fileSize"));
        filePathColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OLLFile, String>("filePath"));
        fileActions.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OLLFile, String>("fileActions"));

        //Заполняем таблицу данными
        overLFilesTable.setItems(oLLFileDataForView);
    }


    public void initDataForView (ObservableList<File> currentOverLimitList) {

        for (int i = 0; i < currentOverLimitList.size(); i++) {
            oLLFileDataForView.add(new OLLFile(currentOverLimitList.get(i).getName(), currentOverLimitList.get(i).length()/1024, currentOverLimitList.get(i).getAbsolutePath(), currentOverLimitList.get(i).getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }


    //Setters and Getters

    public void setCurrentOverLimitList(ObservableList<File> currentOverLimitList) { this.currentOverLimitList = currentOverLimitList; }
    public ObservableList<File> getCurrentOverLimitList() { return currentOverLimitList; }

    public void setDialogStage(Stage OLFilesLayoutStage) {
        this.OLFilesLayoutStage = OLFilesLayoutStage;
    }
```

В `fileActions` (пока временно переделанного в `String`) хочу выводить гиперссылку, которая будет переводить к папке с файлом - и так в каждой строке в этом поле таблицы.

Подскажите, где можно найти пример подобной генерации ссылок в таблице?

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы у тебя выполнялось какое-либо действие при нажатии, тебе необходимо в колонку **fileActions** передать cellFactory, в которой ты уже опишешь, что делать, если у тебя кликнулось на эту ячейку, и затем вызывать метод **Desktop.open(file)**
Т.е. код будет выглядеть примерно так

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
   ...
   fileActions.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OLLFile, String>("fileActions"));
   fileActions.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<OllFile,String>, TableCell<OllFile, String>()
    {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<ConsoleText<T>> param)
        {
            return new CellFactory();
        }
    });
```

Твоя фактори

```
public class CellFactory extends TableCell<OllFile, String> {

    public void CellFactory() {
       this.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                Desktop.open(new File(CellFactory.this.getItem()));
            }
        });

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean b) {
       if (b && item!= null) {
          setText(item.toString);  
    }
}
```

**P.S.** могут быть синтаксические ошибки, т.к. писал на коленке, а в остальном - идея такая.