# добавление ссылок в TableView

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть таблица, и в одну из колонок я хочу добавить ссылки на файлы. На просторах интернета я пока нашел только вот этот [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435334/javafx-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-tableview), но я многое там не пойму, к примеру:
   `ConsoleText<T>` - что за параметр `T` - другие мы не принимаем, почему я не могу просмотреть `call` и `param`, особенно не пойму это:

```
 @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean b) {
            if (b && item!= null) {
                setText(item.toString);
            }
        }
```

В общем помогите мне пожалуйста разобраться, как в `tableView` засунуть ссылку на файл, пример из ссылки полностью идентичен моему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в таблице не будет других действий, можно упростить задачу и повесить действие по открытию файла на двойной клик по строке:

```
tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<T> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                // Делаем что либо с tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
            }
        });
        return row;
    })
```